# How do I add new fields to mongodb in production and query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Structural question about mongo db. I have a node/express/mongoose app querying my mongo database for my rest api and have it running in production.

I am wanting to add new fields to query, but the issue I am having is that a lot of old documents will not have these new fields. Whats the best way to add a new field and query? I have used `field :{ exists: true }` and that works, but how do I query fields if these new fields are true or false?

I want to find all documents and not just if that particular fields exists or not. Not even sure if this is possible, I may need to add the new fields to every single document?

Comment: if this field doesn't exist on a document, it will be treated as true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the field that you are querying on does not exist in any document, that document will be discarded. To demo it, here are the two documents I have in a collection, and of these documents does not have a field I am querying on. Mongo simply returned the document `that matched` the query requirements

**The sample documents**

```
{
    "_id": 2,
    "description": "QUESTION",
    "names": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D",
      "E"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "description": "ANSWER",
    "newField1": "I have some value",  <=== new field only for this doc
    "names": [
      "A2",
      "B2",
      "C2",
      "D2",
      "E2"
    ]
  }
```

**My query**

```
db.collection.find({
  "newField1": "I have some value"
})
```

**the result**

```
{
    "_id": 3,
    "description": "ANSWER",
    "names": [
      "A2",
      "B2",
      "C2",
      "D2",
      "E2"
    ],
    "newField1": "I have some value"
  }
```